# Generación de PDF A - 2

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de crear un pdf A-2 con iText 7 pero me esta saliendo esta excepción:

> iText.Pdfa.PdfA Conformance Exception: 'All the fonts must be
> embedded. This one is not: Times-Bold'.

Por favor si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería enormemente, mi código es este:

```
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter (pdfNewName);

ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties ();

iText.Pdfa.PdfADocument pdf = new iText.Pdfa.PdfADocument (writer, iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_2B, new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputIntent ("Custom", "", 6-2) ", new FileStream (profile, FileMode.Open)));

iText.Layout.Document document = new iText.Layout.Document (pdf);

iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont ExternalSource = iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont (bold, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.WINANSI);

iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph p = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph ();
p.SetFont (externalSource);

document.Add (p);

HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf (htmlString, pdf, properties);
```

Comment: El error dice claramente que no encuentra el font Time-Bold. Seguro que lo estas agregando al generar el pdf?

Comment: fijate si tenes agregada la fuente en tu proyecto y si la tenes agregada fijate en las propiedades del archivo dentro de visual studio ahi tenes opciones de como esta vinculada al proyecto.

Comment: Ya no me arroja la excepción de Time-Bold, pero me esta arrojando otra excepción  
 de Times Roman y ya le ingrese la fuente Times Roman pero me sigue saliendo el error, este es mi codigo.

iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont fuenteExterna = iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(timesRoman, iText.IO.Font.PdfEncodings.WINANSI,true);           iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph p = new iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph();
p.SetFont(fuenteExterna);
document.Add(p);

HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlString, pdf, properties);